# Can we automate the installation of a software using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Per my knowledge, Selenium can automate only web actions. Can we use selenium to automate installation of a software.

Comment: If the whole installation process is webbased, we can use selenium for automation. IF there is any windows based intervention here and there, we can use the support of AutoIT scripts.

Comment: The whole installation is not webbased. Its windows based. Will the AutoIT script accept some input needed during installation process?

Comment: AutoIT can be used to automate window installations and also we can provide user inputs in between. For a sample software installation example, you can refer to [this](http://www.technibble.com/automation-with-autoit-tutorial-part-1/) link.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will refer to the link you have provided.

Comment: If the software is an msi package you may be able to silently install it through autoIT or any other framework.  See the [info on msi command-line here](http://communities.quest.com/community/uwm/blog/2012/09/21/the-complete-guide-to-msi-switches-for-silent-software-installation)

Comment: you can automate as long as the installation is web-based. hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for your responses. 
If the installation of a software is completely windows based and does not involve browser based actions, we cannot automate the installation of the software. In such cases, we need to use tools like AutoIT. Selenium automates only browser actions.

Comment: you can also use ROBOT API by key combinations :-)

Answer (score 0):

*"Selenium is a portable software testing framework for web applications."*

Answer (score 0):

No

And just to make sure I was clear (and hit the minimum character limit)

**No!**